# How can I avoid a warning about the PHP mbstring extension?

Tags: 6, updating

In the process of updating a Drupal module (update.php, very first instance) have found this message:

> "Operations on Unicode strings are emulated on a best-effort basis. Install the PHP mbstring extension for improved Unicode support. (Currently using Unicode library Standard PHP)"

Does anyone know the implications of not installing this PHP extension in Drupal 6?

Comment: please vote for reopen if an answer to this Drupal requirement is suitable. I try to ask about implications in Drupal for when is not possible install this PHP extension in Drupal 6. The question is about experiences with Drupal for when is not used the extension: is possible avoid the extension? I mean, regarding implications in Drupal, the question is about Drupal behavior if this extension does not installed. the questions is not about good hosting, or howto install extensions.

Comment: I solved with  `For Linux Mint using PHP 7:
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

and don't forget to run:
sudo service apache2 restart` source   [http://it2.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php]